# POSIX sh syntax for for-loops [SC2039]

Tags: shell, for-loop, posix

The following command works well on my shell :

```
for ((j=0; j<=24; j++))
do > $j.json
done
```

but having the following notification :

> SC2039 In POSIX sh, arithmetic for loops are undefined.

I was wondering what would be the equivalent in POSIX in order not to have interpeting issues on other systems.

Comment: What system or tool is giving such a nice portability hint?

Comment: @Jens http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: http://www.shellcheck.net/ ineed, thx @that-other-guy

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I guess the standards-compliant way of doing it would be something like this:

```
j=0
while [ $j -le 24 ]; do
    true > "$j.json"
    j=$(( j + 1 ))
done
```

Comment: Almost: use `$((++j))` and IIRC a lone redirection is invalid as well, use `: > "$j.json"` instead.

Comment: Yes, POSIX calls `((` for arithmetic a shell extension in http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_01 (it would otherwise be a subshell in a subshell).

Comment: @izabera ah yes, the standard says _The sizeof() operator and the prefix and postfix "++" and "--" operators are not required._. I just edited to change

Comment: also note that `:` is a special builtin, so if that redirection fails for whatever reason (e.g. permissions), that error is fatal.  it's better to use `true` instead of `:` in this case

Answer (score 7):

Another way that should work in a POSIX shell:

```
for j in $(seq 0 24); do
    ...
done
```

Comment: *If* you have the non-POSIX `seq`.

Comment: And you might get some 'unused variable' warnings when using tools like shellcheck (although I am not sure if that should be considered a shellcheck bug).

Comment: Since seq is non-POSIX, you need to include `seq() { j=$1;while [ $j -le $2 ]; do echo $j; j=$(( j + 1 )); done; }`